# jenkins - checkout source based on a parameter

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my jenkins job, I would like to check out different source from SVN based on input parameter.
For example if input is "foo", then checkout source from https://svn/code/foo/trunk. If input is "bar", then checkout source from  https://svn/anotherrepo/bar/trunk.

I would like to do this using parametrized plugin and subversion plugin in Jenkins. Is this possible? If not what are the possible solutions?

I am using Jenkins version 2.22.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

this is possible. declarative Jenkinsfile syntax supports parameters and subversion with the appropriate plugins installed. you can collect the parameters with the parameters block and use the parameters by referencing params.PARAM_NAME like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
  }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'MY_MODULE', defaultValue: 'awesome_module', description: 'What subversion module to checkout?')
  }
  stages {
    stage('hot_stage') {
      steps {
        checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '196ff1ff-c481-4d2e-922b-e32410f8ee13', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: "https://svn/code/${params.MY_MODULE}/trunk"]], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that mega-long checkout step was generated automatically by my jenkins server when i clicked on "Pipeline Syntax" in the left nav of any pipeline job, selected sample step "checkout: General SCM", filled in the options in the jenkins UI and clicked "Generate Pipeline Script".

you're not using absolute latest jenkins, and i'm not exactly sure when the params instruction was added. if that doesn't work, you can probably reference it via env.MY_MODULE.